# Can anyone recommend a numerical optimization book or course note?

Tags: optimization, book-recommendation

My background is primarily in mathematicians. I am familiar with graduate level analysis, linear algebra, numerical linear algebra, but have very limited experience with numerical analysis.

Can anyone recommend a numerical optimization book or course note?

Ideally, it should take advantage of linear algebra and analysis whenever necessary and provide a lot of intuitions because I will primarily be reading on my own. The proofs are secondary, but I will be interested in reading constructive proof that facilitates understanding.

If it is a part of a video lecture, that would very helpful.

My goal is to be able to develop a decent understabding of the core theory and use commonly used numerical optimization techniques effectively (like implemented in script or c++).

Comment: What are you most interested in- implementing methods yourself or how to use methods implemented by others and interpret the results?  Are you interested in parallel/distributed algorithms, or are more conventional serial methods enough?  Are you interested in nonsmooth but convex optimization problems?  Smooth but possibly nonconvex problems?  Problems that are nonconvex and nonsmooth?

Comment: The book Numerical Optimization by Nocedal and Wright is a good introduction.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by numerical optimisation? While not exactly what you are looking for, I would recommend glancing through Golub & Van Loan's Matrix Computations. Also, you might take a look at http://cvxr.com/cvx/.

Comment: @copper.hat Can you take a look at the functions in here: 
 https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html  I would like to understand these methods and learn some theory behind.

Answer (score 4):

I highly recommend the lecture notes from EE236 by Vandenberghe at UCLA.  There are three courses (A, B, and C) and there's a corresponding textbook (Convex Optimization by Boyd and Vandenberghe, which is free online).

Comment: I actually bought that book. I am not sure if the engineering approach is the right way to approach optimization. Plus, a glance at the menus did find methods in here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html

Comment: @user1559897 I'm not sure what you mean by "the engineering approach".  Both Boyd and Vandenberghe are mathematicians, and the text is mathematically rigorous.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend the two recent books by Amir Beck: (1) *Introduction to Nonlinear Optimization* and (2) *First-order methods in Optimization*, SIAM. The other books are fine, but I personally enjoy the clarity and level of details in Beck's books more.

Answer (score 1):

Well, a simple Google search yielded me a [PDF of Nocedal and Wright’s classic Numerical Optimisation, Springer](http://www.%E6%B7%B1%E5%BA%A6%E5%AD%A6%E4%B9%A0.top/literature/Nocedal_Wright_Numerical_optimization_v2.pdf).

In India, the following [NPTEL course](http://nptel.ac.in/courses/106108056/) is highly recommended.

Comment: The OP asks for a recommendation, so presumably s/he is looking for something that you yourself have gone through and judged to be helpful, so I don't see how a textbook that you've found from "a simple Google search" can possibly be an appropriate response.

Comment: @ProjectBook I took the NPTEL course when I studied this, sir..

Comment: When did I mention the NPTEL course? I am only talking about your "a simple Google search" thing. If people come to you and ask for a recommendation for a good movie say, do you just use your "a simple Google search" as well?